# "bash: cannot execute binary file" during nix dockerTools cross-build from MacOS host

Tags: nix

[A great 2016 blog post](http://lethalman.blogspot.com/2016/04/cheap-docker-images-with-nix_15.html) described building minimal Docker images with Nix. The below is a simple example taken from that blog post, modified to support Nix 2.0:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;
dockerTools.buildImage {
  name = "redis";
  runAsRoot = ''
    #!${stdenv.shell}
    ${dockerTools.shadowSetup}
    groupadd -r redis
    useradd -r -g redis -d /data -M redis
    mkdir /data
    chown redis:redis /data
  '';

  config = {
    Cmd = [ "${gosu.bin}/bin/gosu" "redis" "${redis}/bin/redis-server" ];
    ExposedPorts = {
      "6379/tcp" = {};
    };
    WorkingDir = "/data";
    Volumes = {
      "/data" = {};
    };
  };
}
```

Using [`nix-linuxkit`](https://github.com/nix-community/linuxkit-builder) to have an x86_64-linux builder, this fails with an error about a `bash` executable which can't be run:

```
$ nix-build -j 1 --system x86_64-linux redis-small.nix
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/iixmgfhsczc71484vcwqwz2nzlg0rcv1-extra-commands.sh.drv
  /nix/store/jsydsrzs7h9pfnh8m6cxaysa9bafmp2z-redis-config.json.drv
  /nix/store/csfmyw6va3b8dabshliqjkrrdr6n090w-vm-run-stage2.drv
  /nix/store/l0p201r6zjfzsznfb6ykca1l8n09lyb9-vm-run.drv
  /nix/store/s64kqfyggqm60l5j9wy6s1nz39iwkxiw-run-as-root.sh.drv
  /nix/store/zidg0xphc7yjc4n0w3k7wnifz6rlqgzh-docker-layer-redis.drv
  /nix/store/12ahsincv8igv492gzjjvw9s8aaff65i-runtime-deps.drv
  /nix/store/pyx4q2wln2shlnjdp5ng43aqd6iba80d-docker-image-redis.tar.gz.drv
building '/nix/store/jsydsrzs7h9pfnh8m6cxaysa9bafmp2z-redis-config.json.drv'...
/nix/store/6v88ick1cxnn5g91m8qrrqww0lrlr27x-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash: /nix/store/6v88ick1cxnn5g91m8qrrqww0lrlr27x-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
builder for '/nix/store/jsydsrzs7h9pfnh8m6cxaysa9bafmp2z-redis-config.json.drv' failed with exit code 126
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/pyx4q2wln2shlnjdp5ng43aqd6iba80d-docker-image-redis.tar.gz.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/pyx4q2wln2shlnjdp5ng43aqd6iba80d-docker-image-redis.tar.gz.drv' failed
```

The key line here is `/nix/store/6v88ick1cxnn5g91m8qrrqww0lrlr27x-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file`. Using `file` to inspect that, it's genuinely a Linux ELF binary.

---

Incidentally, the same thing also happens with the following one-liner, taken from an answer to StackOverflow question [How to build a Docker container with Nix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375880/how-to-build-a-docker-container-with-nix), also using dockerTools:

```
$ nix-build -j 1 --system x86_64-linux -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage { name = "nix-htop"; contents = pkgs.htop; config = { Cmd = [ "/bin/htop" ]; }; }'
```

...fails similarly:

```
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/gz4lrsjcmxbcmdfpmazwz0wqnb5pbw8k-nix-htop-config.json’
/nix/store/nkq0n2m4shlbdvdq0qijib5zyzgmn0vq-bash-4.4-p12/bin/bash: /nix/store/nkq0n2m4shlbdvdq0qijib5zyzgmn0vq-bash-4.4-p12/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
builder for ‘/nix/store/487mmw8kql56q7h6iq4c7hfzh4k0gv50-nix-htop-config.json.drv’ failed with exit code 126
```

Is `dockerTools` the common thread here?

Comment: I get the same error as you. Did you manage to get to the bottom of this Charles? Any workarounds?

Comment: My recollection is that I switched from dockerTools to using a different toolchain, something using xhyve directly with Nix tooling maintained upstream, but I'm not using it any longer today and don't remember what it was. Apologies about that -- if I'd remembered asking this question, I would presumably have answered it at the time, when the solution was fresh in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/building-a-docker-image-on-macos-with-remote-builder/7541/2) worked for me. Instead of using `--system x86_64-linux`, you can use `--argstr system x86_64-linux` with a nix expression like this

```
{ system ? "x86_64-linux", pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { inherit system; } }:
...
```

For example

```
nix-build -j 1 --argstr system x86_64-linux -E '{ system ? "x86_64-linux", pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { inherit system; } }: pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage { name = "nix-htop"; contents = pkgs.htop; config = { Cmd = [ "/bin/htop" ]; }; }'
```